# fetchMock: uncaught typeError

Tags: reactjs, fetch-mock

I have mocked my API-Respones with fetchMock (v.5.13.1). I have been working with it for a quite long time now and I didn't see this kind of behaviour yet.

I mocked two GET responses that are very similar.

```
fetchMock.get('glob:*/shippings/',"results":[
{"id": "1234", "status": "RELEASED", "foo": "bar"},
{"id": "5678", "status": "CREATED", "foo": "bar"},)

fetchMock.get('glob:*/shipping/myId1234',
{"id": "1234", "status": "RELEASED", "foo": "bar"})
```

Now, the first one works properly, but the second get returns me this error message:

> fetch-mock.js:187 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid status RELEASED passed
>   on response object. To respond with a JSON object that has status as a
>   property assign the object to body e.g. {"body": {"status:
>   "registered"}}

I have an assumption, that I cant mock some response that contains a status, because thats in a way a reserved attribute for status codes, but I am not quite sure and I cant find any similar errors online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second request to fetchMock, it assumes `status` to be one of the standard codes supplied as an integer. According to the docs, the config supplied to `fetchMock` expects the following params

> If an object only contains properties from among those listed below it
>   is used to configure a Response to return
>
> **body: String | Object**
>
> Set the Response body. See the non-config Object section of the docs
>   below for behaviour when passed an Object
>
> Server responded ok { token: 'abcdef' }
>
> **status: Integer**
>
> Set the Response status
>
> 200, 404, 503
>
> **headers: Object**
>
> Set the Response headers
>
> {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
>
> **redirectUrl: String**
>
> The url from which the Response should claim to originate from (to
>   imitate followed directs). Will also set redirected: true on the
>   response
>
> **throws: Error**
>
> Force fetch to return a Promise rejected with the value of throws
>
> new TypeError('Failed to fetch')

However for a custom status attribute you can respond with a body

```
fetchMock.get('glob:*/shipping/myId1234', {
    body: {"id": "1234", "status": "RELEASED", "foo": "bar"}
})
```